# Story about prisoners on a spaceship forced to perform repetitive tasks

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, spaceship

In this short story, the main character is locked in a small plain room.  Creatures of different "shapes" enter the room each "day" and monitor him as he is forced to watch a bubble in a tube and adjust a valve so that the bubble stays between two lines.  When the bubble falls outside the lines the creature monitoring him sets off a loud alarm or otherwise provides negative reinforcement.  The creatures are described abstractly, for instance one is a triangle, a cube, etc.